# Mlkit digitink get score of result

Tags: android, google-mlkit

The recognizer provides the text, but doesn't provide a score to the java program
Could this feature be added ?
( https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition/android?hl=en ) : says that score is not implemented for text recognition, but for shape classifiers

In debug window in android studio, we see the score that the native code print in log :
I/native: I0000 00:00:1694769784.475278   22551 helper.cc:162] Recognition result: o with score: 58.5046

I have tried :
float score = result.getCandidates().get(0).getScore();

but it fails -> Exception

recognizer
.recognize(this.ink,recognitionContext )
.onSuccessTask(
result -> {

```
          if (cancelled.get() || result.getCandidates().isEmpty()) {
            return Tasks.forResult(null);
          }

          currentResult = new RecognizedInk(ink, result.getCandidates().get(0).getText());
```

Comment: See https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/606